# How to replace a token from the string in JavaScript using REGEX

Tags: javascript, regex, string, replace

I have such template "text %variable.key% text". The variable.key is the variable.
And I need to rename such variables to "text "+variable.key+" text", to make them work.

I have tried to do something like this:

```
var tpl = "text %variable.key% text";
tpl = tpl.replace(/%(.*?)%/, function(a,b) {
    return eval('b');
});
```

but it also returns a string.

Can somebody tell me how to do this?

Comment: fyi, `eval` is *strongly* discouraged.

Comment: Besides the *evilness* of `eval`, I think you meant to use `eval(b)`

Comment: in addition to Daniel White's comment: try searching for `[js] eval evil` on SO if you want to know more.

Comment: Thank you for inform me. I didn't knew it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's easy to do without using `eval` at all:

```
function getValue(path) {
    var target = this;
    path.split('.').forEach(function (branch) {
        if (typeof target === "undefined") return;
        target = (typeof target[branch] === "undefined") ? undefined : target[branch];
    });

    return target;
}
```

If you want to get properties starting from `window` you can just call `getValue("path.to.property")`. If you want to start from some other root object, use `getValue.call(rootObject, "path.to.property")`.

The function could also be adapted to take the root object as an optional first parameter, but the idea remains the same.

[**See it in action**](http://jsfiddle.net/jA3m9/).

**Important:** This will not work on Internet Explorer < 9 because `Array.prototype.forEach` will not exist. You can fix that with

```
if (!Array.prototype.forEach) {
    Array.prototype.forEach = function(fun /*, thisPointer */) {
        var len = this.length;
        if (typeof fun != "function") throw new TypeError();

        var thisPointer = arguments[1];
        for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            if (i in this) {
                fun.call(thisPointer, this[i], i, this);
            }
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: After all, there is a big hemorrhoid with the window[b]. So I will use your solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Another variant, without eval() , works with simple variable, or object:

```
var var_name = 'value';

// object
var obj = new Object();
 obj.prop = 'some val';

var tpl = "text %obj.prop% text %var_name% text";
tpl = tpl.replace(/%(.*?)%/gi, function(a,b) {
  var iv = b.split('.');
  return (iv.length == 2) ? window[iv[0]][iv[1]] : window[iv[0]];
});

// test
alert(tpl);
```

Comment: Just a little fix for objects should be added

Answer (score 1):

```
var tpl = "text %variable.key% text";
tpl = tpl.replace(/%(.*?)%/, function(a,b) {
    return eval(b);// remove quote.
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/58gBF/)

Comment: yeap, it's realy works. Thanks. But is there any other possibility to do the same but with no eval?

Answer (score 1):

Your code is correct but you need to eval `b`, not `'b'`:

```
var tpl = "text %variable.key% text";
tpl = tpl.replace(/%(.*?)%/, function(a,b) {
    return eval(b);
});
```

As was mentioned in the comments, using eval is not the way to go. You could get the variable value like this as wel:

```
var tpl = "text %variable.key% text";
tpl = tpl.replace(/%(.*?)%/, function(a,b) {
    return window[b];
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ChmZy/2/)